# publish on docker desktop is too slow

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget

i'm dot net core developer and i'm trying to publish on docker
but every time i'm publishing my project on docker desktop or hub on server, it takes a long time
every time it download all nuget from https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer

Is there a way to not download every time or to download locally

one of my dockerfile is :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/Localization/Localization.API/Localization.API.csproj", "Services/Localization/Localization.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/Localization/Localization.API/Localization.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/Localization/Localization.API"
RUN dotnet build "Localization.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Localization.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Localization.API.dll"]
```

and my output is :

```
Determining projects to restore...
#20 10.86   Skipping project "/src/BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.Common/Core.Common.csproj" because it was not found.
#20 10.89   Skipping project "/src/BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.Common/Core.Common.csproj" because it was not found.
#20 80.99   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.5.0.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json/5.0.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json.5.0.0.nupkg'.
#20 80.99   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json/5.0.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json.5.0.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 80.99     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 81.40   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.5.0.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration/5.0.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.5.0.0.nupkg'.
#20 81.40   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration/5.0.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.5.0.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 81.40     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 82.15   Failed to download package 'MediatR.9.0.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/mediatr/9.0.0/mediatr.9.0.0.nupkg'.
#20 82.15   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/mediatr/9.0.0/mediatr.9.0.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 82.15     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 90.91   Failed to download package 'Autofac.6.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/autofac/6.1.0/autofac.6.1.0.nupkg'.
#20 90.91   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/autofac/6.1.0/autofac.6.1.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 90.91     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 94.41   Restored /src/Services/WebSite/WebSite.Infrastructure/WebSite.Infrastructure.csproj (in 1.33 min).
#20 94.67   Restored /src/Services/WebSite/WebSite.Domain/WebSite.Domain.csproj (in 171 ms).
#20 99.41   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.options.configurationextensions/index.json'.
#20 99.41   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 99.41     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 105.2   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.options.configurationextensions/index.json'.
#20 105.3   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 105.3     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 109.2   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggerui/index.json'.
#20 109.2   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 109.2     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 109.2   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggergen/index.json'.
#20 109.2   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 109.2     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 109.2   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.apidescription.server/index.json'.
#20 109.2   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 109.2     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 109.2   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices/index.json'.
#20 109.2   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 109.2     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 109.2   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation/index.json'.
#20 109.2   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 109.2     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 109.2   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swagger/index.json'.
#20 109.2   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 109.2     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 111.3   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog.sinks.periodicbatching/index.json'.
#20 111.3   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 111.3     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 111.3   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog.sinks.file/index.json'.
#20 111.3   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 111.3     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 111.3   Failed to download package 'Serilog.2.9.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog/2.9.0/serilog.2.9.0.nupkg'.
#20 111.3   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 111.3     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 111.3   Failed to download package 'Serilog.2.8.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog/2.8.0/serilog.2.8.0.nupkg'.
#20 111.3   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 111.3     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 111.3   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.linq/index.json'.
#20 111.3   Resource temporarily unavailable (api.nuget.org:443)
#20 111.3     Resource temporarily unavailable
#20 116.9   Restored /src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj (in 1.7 min).
#20 160.8   Restored /src/BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/WebHost.Customization.csproj (in 43.97 sec).
#20 160.9   Restored /src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj (in 35 ms).
#20 160.9   Restored /src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/EventBus.csproj (in 8 ms).
#20 160.9   Restored /src/BuildingBlocks/Core/Core/Core.csproj (in 42 ms).
#20 169.2   Failed to download package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.debug/4.3.0/system.diagnostics.debug.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 169.2   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.debug/4.3.0/system.diagnostics.debug.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 169.2     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 176.3   Failed to download package 'System.Linq.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.linq/4.3.0/system.linq.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 176.3   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.linq/4.3.0/system.linq.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 176.3     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 176.6   Failed to download package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.6.1.4' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggergen/6.1.4/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggergen.6.1.4.nupkg'.
#20 176.6   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggergen/6.1.4/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggergen.6.1.4.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 176.6     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 176.7   Failed to download package 'System.IO.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.io/4.3.0/system.io.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 176.7   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.io/4.3.0/system.io.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 176.7     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 176.9   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.2.0.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/2.0.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder.2.0.0.nupkg'.
#20 176.9   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/2.0.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder.2.0.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 176.9     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 177.7   Failed to download package 'System.Xml.XDocument.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.xml.xdocument/4.3.0/system.xml.xdocument.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 177.7   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.xml.xdocument/4.3.0/system.xml.xdocument.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 177.7     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 178.1   Failed to download package 'System.Runtime.Handles.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.handles/4.3.0/system.runtime.handles.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 178.1   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.handles/4.3.0/system.runtime.handles.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 178.1     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 179.2   Failed to download package 'System.Linq.Expressions.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.linq.expressions/4.3.0/system.linq.expressions.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 179.2   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.linq.expressions/4.3.0/system.linq.expressions.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 179.2     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 179.4   Failed to download package 'System.IO.Compression.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.io.compression/4.3.0/system.io.compression.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 179.4   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.io.compression/4.3.0/system.io.compression.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 179.4     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 179.4   Failed to download package 'System.Net.Sockets.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.sockets/4.3.0/system.net.sockets.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 179.4   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.sockets/4.3.0/system.net.sockets.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 179.4     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 179.6   Failed to download package 'System.Collections.NonGeneric.4.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.collections.nongeneric/4.0.1/system.collections.nongeneric.4.0.1.nupkg'.
#20 179.6   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.collections.nongeneric/4.0.1/system.collections.nongeneric.4.0.1.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 179.6     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 179.8   Failed to download package 'System.Collections.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.collections/4.3.0/system.collections.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 179.8   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.collections/4.3.0/system.collections.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 179.8     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 179.9   Failed to download package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.primitives/4.3.0/system.security.cryptography.primitives.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 179.9   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.primitives/4.3.0/system.security.cryptography.primitives.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 179.9     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 180.2   Failed to download package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.tools/4.3.0/system.diagnostics.tools.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 180.2   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.tools/4.3.0/system.diagnostics.tools.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 180.2     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 180.4   Failed to download package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices/4.3.0/system.runtime.interopservices.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 180.4   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices/4.3.0/system.runtime.interopservices.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 180.4     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 181.8   Failed to download package 'System.Reflection.Extensions.4.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection.extensions/4.0.1/system.reflection.extensions.4.0.1.nupkg'.
#20 181.8   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection.extensions/4.0.1/system.reflection.extensions.4.0.1.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 181.8     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 181.9   Failed to download package 'System.Runtime.Numerics.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.numerics/4.3.0/system.runtime.numerics.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 181.9   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.numerics/4.3.0/system.runtime.numerics.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 181.9     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 182.0   Failed to download package 'System.Reflection.4.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection/4.1.0/system.reflection.4.1.0.nupkg'.
#20 182.0   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection/4.1.0/system.reflection.4.1.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 182.1     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 182.3   Failed to download package 'System.Threading.4.0.11' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading/4.0.11/system.threading.4.0.11.nupkg'.
#20 182.3   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading/4.0.11/system.threading.4.0.11.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 182.3     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 182.8   Failed to download package 'System.Runtime.Extensions.4.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.extensions/4.1.0/system.runtime.extensions.4.1.0.nupkg'.
#20 182.8   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.extensions/4.1.0/system.runtime.extensions.4.1.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 182.8     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 183.1   Failed to download package 'Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.2' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/12.0.2/newtonsoft.json.12.0.2.nupkg'.
#20 183.1   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/12.0.2/newtonsoft.json.12.0.2.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 183.1     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 183.9   Failed to download package 'Serilog.2.8.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog/2.8.0/serilog.2.8.0.nupkg'.
#20 183.9   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog/2.8.0/serilog.2.8.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 183.9     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 183.9   Failed to download package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.encoding/4.3.0/system.security.cryptography.encoding.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 183.9   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.encoding/4.3.0/system.security.cryptography.encoding.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 183.9     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 185.8   Failed to download package 'System.Net.Http.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http/4.3.0/system.net.http.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 185.8   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http/4.3.0/system.net.http.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 185.8     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 186.0   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.3.1.2' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions/3.1.2/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions.3.1.2.nupkg'.
#20 186.0   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions/3.1.2/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions.3.1.2.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 186.0     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 187.0   Failed to download package 'System.Reflection.Primitives.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection.primitives/4.3.0/system.reflection.primitives.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 187.0   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection.primitives/4.3.0/system.reflection.primitives.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 187.0     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 187.8   Failed to download package 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.5.0.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/5.0.0/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource.5.0.0.nupkg'.
#20 187.8   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/5.0.0/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource.5.0.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 187.8     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 188.6   Failed to download package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/9.0.1/newtonsoft.json.9.0.1.nupkg'.
#20 188.6   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/9.0.1/newtonsoft.json.9.0.1.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 188.6     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 188.9   Failed to download package 'System.Runtime.4.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime/4.1.0/system.runtime.4.1.0.nupkg'.
#20 188.9   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime/4.1.0/system.runtime.4.1.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 188.9     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 189.2   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/5.0.1/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.5.0.1.nupkg'.
#20 189.2   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/5.0.1/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.5.0.1.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 189.2     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 189.3   Failed to download package 'System.Globalization.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.globalization/4.3.0/system.globalization.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 189.3   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.globalization/4.3.0/system.globalization.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 189.3     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 190.0   Failed to download package 'Serilog.Sinks.File.4.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog.sinks.file/4.1.0/serilog.sinks.file.4.1.0.nupkg'.
#20 190.0   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog.sinks.file/4.1.0/serilog.sinks.file.4.1.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 190.0     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 190.5   Failed to download package 'FluentValidation.10.2.3' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentvalidation/10.2.3/fluentvalidation.10.2.3.nupkg'.
#20 190.5   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentvalidation/10.2.3/fluentvalidation.10.2.3.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 190.5     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 192.2   Failed to download package 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.4.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.regularexpressions/4.1.0/system.text.regularexpressions.4.1.0.nupkg'.
#20 192.2   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.regularexpressions/4.1.0/system.text.regularexpressions.4.1.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 192.2     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 192.3   Failed to download package 'System.Runtime.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime/4.3.0/system.runtime.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 192.3   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime/4.3.0/system.runtime.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 192.3     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 192.7   Failed to download package 'System.Text.Encoding.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encoding/4.3.0/system.text.encoding.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 192.7   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encoding/4.3.0/system.text.encoding.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 192.7     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 197.2   Failed to download package 'System.Collections.Concurrent.4.0.12' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.collections.concurrent/4.0.12/system.collections.concurrent.4.0.12.nupkg'.
#20 197.2   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.collections.concurrent/4.0.12/system.collections.concurrent.4.0.12.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 197.2     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 205.0   Failed to download package 'System.Linq.4.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.linq/4.1.0/system.linq.4.1.0.nupkg'.
#20 205.0   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.linq/4.1.0/system.linq.4.1.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 205.0     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 217.0   Failed to download package 'System.Reflection.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection/4.3.0/system.reflection.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 217.0   The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection/4.3.0/system.reflection.4.3.0.nupkg' has timed out after 100000ms.
#20 218.2   Failed to download package 'Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.2.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog.sinks.periodicbatching/2.3.0/serilog.sinks.periodicbatching.2.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 218.2   The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog.sinks.periodicbatching/2.3.0/serilog.sinks.periodicbatching.2.3.0.nupkg' has timed out after 100000ms.
#20 243.8   Failed to download package 'System.Reflection.4.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection/4.1.0/system.reflection.4.1.0.nupkg'.
#20 243.8   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection/4.1.0/system.reflection.4.1.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 243.8     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 254.7   Restored /src/BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.WebApi/Core.WebApi.csproj (in 1.56 min).
#20 258.4   Failed to download package 'System.Reflection.Primitives.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection.primitives/4.3.0/system.reflection.primitives.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#20 258.4   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection.primitives/4.3.0/system.reflection.primitives.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 258.4     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 262.4   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/5.0.1/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.5.0.1.nupkg'.
#20 262.4   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/5.0.1/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.5.0.1.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#20 262.4     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#20 318.8   Restored /src/Services/WebSite/WebSite.API/WebSite.API.csproj (in 3.73 min).
```

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: You have an awful lot of timeouts in there for NuGet packages. What happens if you attempt to download one directly in a browser, like [System.Linq.4.3.0](https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.linq/4.3.0/system.linq.4.3.0.nupkg)?

Comment: why evert time connect to nuget and download from there?

Comment: Are you fetching your packages in a layer after copying your code in? That will cause your code to be rebuilt every time.

Comment: Set up a local nuget mirror - for example using nexus - and tell your project to use that only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the flag *--disable-parallel*. It completes but it takes way too long.

You can also set your own nuget file with option --configfile (maybe experiment with the attribute *maxHttpRequestsPerSource*, try to lower its value to 5 or 10).

For me, setting a nuget file + packages folder (*--packages*) kinda worked, but I still get some random failures from time to time.

There are many flavors of this problem floating around so I'll leave some links that helped me get around this problem, even though no certain solution is to be found:

- https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10275
- https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1670
- https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9020